# Resteasy Client java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response is closed

Tags: java, resteasy

I am getting below exception in RestEasy client -3.0.8

> 12:46:19,724 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response is closed.

I have write below code

```
client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(request.getUrl());
Response response = target.request().accept(APPLICATION_TYPE_XML).header(TOKEN, request.getToken()).post(Entity.entity(request.getXmlObject(), APPLICATION_TYPE_XML));
output = response.readEntity(String.class);
if (response.getStatus() != SUCCESS_CREATE) {
 //Do Something
} else {
 String classType = ClassFactory.getClassNameFromUrl(request.getUrl());
 if (null != classType && !classType.isEmpty()) {
  Long Id = (Long) response.readEntity(ClassFactory.getClassMethod(classType)).getId();

 }
```

Now this line `Long Id = (Long) response.readEntity(ClassFactory.getClassMethod(classType)).getId();` throwing exception . Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading the response closes the response. 
So when you call `response.readEntity(String.class);`
this will lead to an error when you repeat the read with `response.readEntity(ClassFactory.getClassMethod(classType)).getId();`

You can show this easily by repeating the first readEntity in a loop. Read the response once into the most convenient form and convert it if necessary from there.

Answer (score 5):

You can buffer the body response to allow multiple calls to readEntity():

```
response.bufferEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you solved? I 've faced a similar problem.

Im running in WildFly 9 
My REST Resource is defined as

```
@Path("fake")
public interface FakeService {

     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
     public String get();
}
```

And the implementation

```
public class Fake implements FakeService{
    public String get(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

And my client code is

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
**ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/fake");**

FakeService simple = target.proxy(FakeService.class);
System.out.println(simple.get());
```

After looking  my "server.log" I've found that the excepction is throwed because there is a warning before,

```
WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-24) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: **http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/fake/fake**
```

The URL add an extra path  (fake is twice). I've changed my cliente code to 
    **ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/");**

(without the path of the resource I am proxying) and it worked.